# How to limit the number of email send even if it is reading other email address from list?

Tags: grails

I got this problem where i have to limit the numbers of emails send to a certain number of users from a given list? I am using grails Send Mail plugin to send the email. But now wants to limit the emails to be sent to a particular number for ceratain period of time n start again

Answer (score 0):

More detail would be helpful.

There isn't anything built-in to the mail plugin for this, and much of how to solve it depends on the requirements around the durability of the timers and the volume of e-mails and number of users that we're talking about.

If we're just spitballing, I'd assume that this is a crucial part of your infrastructure and something worth installing [Redis](http://redis.io) for.  Redis is great at keeping track of this kind of information (counters, timeouts, key value store, etc).  Check out [Antirez's post on taking advantage of Redis in your stack](http://antirez.com/post/take-advantage-of-redis-adding-it-to-your-stack.html/) and you should get some ideas on how it could be used.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the [Grails Redis plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/redis), so I've got some bias, but I have bias because I think Redis is a good tech.